# React, how to access child ref in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to access a child Ref in the parent's parent, I don't seem to be able to figure it out, does anyone know how I can achieve this,

```
// Child
const RightMenu = ({t}) => {

  const juraLiveIconRef = useRef();

  return (
     <Row className="pt-4">
        <Col>
          <img
            ref={juraLiveIconRef}
            src={require("../../assets/jura-live-grey.png")}
          />
        </Col>
     </Row>
  )
}

 //Parent1
const BottomMenu = ({ t}) => {

   <div className="bottom-menu-right-menu">
      <RightMenu />
   </div>

}

 //Parent2
const Home = ({ t }) => {

   <div>
    <BottomMenu />
   </div>
}
```

I need to access the ref in Home component(parent2), any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lift your `ref` to `Parent` and append it inside `Child`

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const ref = useRef(null)

    return <Child parentRef={ref} />
}

const Child = props => <GrandChild {...props}/>

const GrandChild = ({ parentRef }) => <div ref={parentRef} />
```

[image: Edit keen-sky-g9yxj]

You can pass a `ref` down like a normal `prop` as long as you don't call it `ref`

Comment: I think we should use this technique to pass a ref https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Not necessarily. `ForwardRef` is just overkill here